# NFS fclose/fwrite behave differently when the code is compiled by -g and -O3 -march

Tags: c++, file

My code does the following code on NFS

1. fopen a file
2. fwrite 16M bytes 16384 times
3. fclose the file

When it is compiled with `-g`, 2) takes 170s, 3) takes 125s

When it is compiled with `-O3 -march`, 2) takes 100s, 3) takes 263s

That 2) is faster with `-O3` makes sense to me, while I do not know why 3) gets slower than with `-g`. And the total time (363s) of `-O3` is slower than `-g` (295s).

I measured time by the following code

```
 std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
 std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds;
 start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 // do some thing
 end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 elapsed_seconds = end-start;
 std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
```

Comment: 1) Rather than describe the code, posting the true code is better - without that, the question is unclear.  2) Is it C as tagged or C++ as suggested by the measuring code?

Comment: std namespace is used in C++

Comment: Note that benchmarking I/O performance is fraught with peril. Your disk is a shared resource, and if anything else is using it at the same time as you run your benchmark this can throw things off. It's entirely probable you just benchmarked the disk load on that server, especially if you only did the benchmark once each. To get a better idea, run the benchmark multiple times, randomly choosing which version, and graph them. Even better, boot into single user mode so you know there's nothing else hogging the disk.

Comment: I did the experiments a few times. The results are similar. But it makes sense to run more times to see if this result is stable.

Comment: I made a quick diff using the compiler-explorer and don't see anything, that would suggest a hick-up. So it's propably a measuring problem. https://godbolt.org/g/199twh

Comment: I just recalled that my filesystem is NFS. Not sure if this could make things different. I updated the title and the question.